# Can a two-dimensional array be initialized in the Unity Inspector?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

If I write in a class which is derived from `MonoBehaviour`

```
[SerializeField] private int [,] TwoDimensionalArray;
```

it cannot be initialized from the inspector. Can I write a script which would let me do that?

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked several times in this and other forums:
[example 1](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-i-serialize-multidimensional-arrays.988704/),
[example 2](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1485842/serialize-custom-multidimensional-array-from-inspe.html)

There are several ways to approach this problem, with the most elegant solution being to create your own `PropertyDrawer`. This is what the [official unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PropertyDrawer.html) says about them:

> Base class to derive custom property drawers from. Use this to create custom drawers for your own Serializable classes or for script variables with custom PropertyAttributes. PropertyDrawers have two uses: Customize the GUI of every instance of a Serializable class. Customize the GUI of script members with custom PropertyAttributes.

I found a [tutorial](https://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/editor/custom-data/) that gives a good overview of how to use them (although it doesn`t directly address multidimensional arrays).

If that seems like overkill to you, there are simpler (and lazier) solutions. For example, you could use a list or one-dimensional array to display/initialize your array in the inspector and convert it to a two-dimensional array on `Start()` or `Awake()`. You can even do this while still in the editor by using `OnValidate()`.